# Singleton instance of WebView2 control used across multiple WinForm instances. Is it supported?

Tags: webview2

We have legacy VB.NET application which uses IE Web Browser Control.
Browser form (Win Form) has been designed placing IE Web Browser control.
Application processes the server actions sequentially -

Creates instance of Browser form, in turn creates instance of Web Browser control.
Navigates to action URL,
User responds to rendered action.
Application close/dispose the Browser form & in turn close Web Browser control
Takes next action for processing, repeats steps from 1 to 4.
First action usually the login action, asks for authentication, user supplies user name and password, it supports both - Basic authentication & Form based authentication.
Web Browser Control/WinINet automatically shares the login credentials (Authorization headers in case of basic authentication) & cookies across server request even though we are creating new instance to process each new request.
It maintains browser session across different instances created.
Application relied on this capability & not required to store credentials and explicitly adding Authorization header and/or cookies on the http request.

We are now replacing Web Browser Control with WebView2, but observed that WebView2 does not share Authorization headers and/or cookies across different instances of WebView2, We have created instance of WebView2 with default CoreWebView2Environment settings.
First login request is processed, asks for authentication, user supplies user name and password, WebView2 instance get closed,
New instance get created to process the next request but again asks for Authentication.
How can we achieve the capability as provided by Web Browser Control ?

Can we have a singleton instance of WebView2 control used across multiple WinForm.
Once WebView2 control singleton instance is initialized, added to the WinForm controls list,
WinForm is closed and WebView2 control singleton instance is removed from the WinForm control list.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you create a WebView2 it has an environment with a user data folder. The user data folder is where all the persisted state like localStorage, cookies, indexedDB and so on is stored. As long as you use the same user data folder you will get the same cookies in future sessions. But if you have session specific data like cached HTTP auth, you'll need to make sure you are using the same environment instance between WebView2s. You can either try to reuse the same one WebView2 again and again, or you can keep a separate hidden WebView2 just to ensure that the environment session is kept alive.